# Mediaplayer not getting any sound

Tags: android, eclipse, audio

I've got a bit of a weird problem which has only just started occurring. Up until this point everything was working fine. My app only plays mediaplayer sounds when headphones are connected to the phone, if they aren't then it plays but no sound out of the phone speakers. Like I said everything was working fine, I'm releasing the mediaplayer when necessary. Is it a problem with my phone or has any body else ever come across this problem? It's perplexing me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to take a look at your phone external speaker, my phone used to have this issue, I thought it was blown, but I took it out, gladly, my s4 has an detachable external speaker with a few screws holding it in place, then I kinda wiped the dust off the contact point, put it back, it sounded, the problem was, somehow the contact point between the speaker and the slot that holds the speaker became loose causing it to not receive data from the device which was weird. You could try this, but if it doesnt sound afterwards, your phone got a problem. Also make sure the volume is not at 0. Hope this helps you a little, but may luck be with you.